# Rails 4.2 capistrano 3 deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, deployment, capistrano, vps

I am totally new to rails deployment. After googling, I still find it hard to understand how to deploy rails apps.

So, my questions are:

1. After setting up the VPS with all rails dependencies, where do I store my codebase? The root directory of the VPS or some specific locations e.g. `www/` or `public/`?
2. Should I upload the whole rails app folder or just part of it? I have paperclip in my rails app, and paperclip creates a `system/` directory in the `public/` folder, so should I upload `system/`?
3. In Capistrano 3, there is a repo_url field, I know they support `file://, https://, ssh://, or svn+ssh://`, but most of the articles about capistrano put github repositories into that. However, I do not have such a github repo. What should I input then?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: About #3, what do you use for managing source code if you are not using github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [set up your own private git server](http://tedfelix.com/software/git-server.html), then in deploy.rb you can put something like

`set :repo_url, 'ssh://user@server_ip/path/to/your_git_repo.git'`

When you commit your changes to the git repo, you do not have to upload the app to the server. Capistrano will upload the app for you when you deploy.

where do i put my code base? This is determined by what you put in `deploy.rb` e.g

`set :deploy_to, '/path/to/my_codebase'`

Whether to upload the `/system` directory will depend on whether you want the paperclip images on your version control. If not you can add the directory to `gitignore`. Here is a [tutorial](https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04) on how to deploy on ubuntu 14.04 passenger and NGINX. if you are not using Passenger and Nginx you can skip to how to configure capistrano and make adjustments depending on your setup.

**EDIT**

You need to install git on your development machine and set up a git server on your VPS as explained on the link above, add your remote server to your local machine using

`git remote add origin <server>`

where 'server' is the url to your git repo in the VPS e.g.

`ssh://VPS_user@VPS_ip/path/to/your_git_repo.git`

Now when you commit and push your changes to the server, capistrano will deploy the latest version on your git server.

[Here is a link with a guide on how to get started with git](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/)

Comment: Does that mean I MUST have a remote git repo in order to deploy through capistrano??I am sensitive to git as I seldom use git...

Comment: The remote git repo can be in the same VPS where you are deploying your application. The only condition is that the user deploying should have both read and write permissions to the directory where the repo is located. in this case you put this in deploy.rb `set :repo_url, 'ssh://your_vps_username@your_vps_ip/path/to/git_repo.git'`. I'll edit the answer shortly with a link on an easy how-to get started with git.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is that I need to first git push my local codebase to the remote git repo, then run the cap deploy command? Or I just need to cap deploy, Capistrano will then push my latest codebase and consequently deploy the app?

Comment: You need to run both the git push command and cap deploy command every time you make changes

Comment: If I use `repo_url, 'ssh://your_vps_username@your_vps_ip/path/to/git_repo.git'`. Does that mean anyone who can guess my git path has the authority to clone my codebase? Any security here??

Comment: No this only works if you have copied server's public keys to your development machine using: `ssh-copy-id vps_username@vps_ip` which means no other computer has access to your login credentials

Answer (score 1):

Answers to the specific questions raised:

> After setting up the VPS with all rails dependencies, where do I store
>   my codebase? The root directory of the VPS or some specific locations
>   e.g. www/ or public/?

It will be deployed to the folder pointed by `:deploy_to` parameter. If not specified, `:deploy_to` defaults to `/var/www/#{fetch(:application)` See: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/05f63f5f333bb261f2a4c4497174361c48143252/lib/capistrano/defaults.rb#L3

> Should I upload the whole rails app folder or just part of it? I have
>   paperclip in my rails app, and paperclip creates a system/ directory
>   in the public/ folder, so should I upload system/?

Paperclip `system` folder is specific to the environment; each environment (development, production,...) will have its own `system` folder which will store the files uploaded on that specific environment. This folder should not be part of the code being deployed.

The recommended way of handing such folders is the keep them in a shared folder on the server, and create symlinks in the current version of the code so that the same folder is used for storing/retrieving attachments. See `Section 3. Update custom links` section in http://robmclarty.com/blog/how-to-deploy-a-rails-4-app-with-git-and-capistrano for more details about this.

As mentioned there, the same applies to `config/database.yml` file, and any other file containing environment specific configurations.

> In Capistrano 3, there is a repo_url field, I know they support
>   file://, https://, ssh://, or svn+ssh://, but most of the articles
>   about capistrano put github repositories into that. However, I do not
>   have such a github repo. What should I input then?

Depends on where the code you are deploying is stored. If it is in a local folder, use the `file:://` format to specify where the files are located.